# edits to a max_int for an array of n ints

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, formula

Considering an array of n integers, 1-n. with each number in range(1, n) included exactly once.

find the average number of edits to a stored max_int variable, for any permutation of the array, as you do an in-order traversal of the array.

for example:
If n=2, the two possible permutations are  [1,2]  and [2,1].
In the case [1,2], there are two edits to the max_int variable (once for the first element, once for the second)
In the case[2,1], there is one edit to the max_int variable (once or the first variable, andwhen you reach the second, you find 2>1 and no edit is made)

So the answer for n=2 is 3/n = 3/2.

similarly, for n=3:

[1, 2, 3]  gives  3  edits

[1, 3, 2]  gives  2  edits

[2, 1, 3]  gives  2  edits

[2, 3, 1]  gives  2  edits

[3, 1, 2]  gives  1  edits

[3, 2, 1]  gives  1  edits

so 11 total, avg is 11/3

I'm looking for a FORMULA, (probably a summation?) not just code that makes it work. I already wrote code to find it but STILL can’t abstract the formula.

Example for n = 4:
 [1, 2, 3, 4]  gives  4  edits

[1, 2, 4, 3]  gives  3  edits

[1, 3, 2, 4]  gives  3  edits

[1, 3, 4, 2]  gives  3  edits

[1, 4, 2, 3]  gives  2  edits

[1, 4, 3, 2]  gives  2  edits

[2, 1, 3, 4]  gives  3  edits

[2, 1, 4, 3]  gives  2  edits

[2, 3, 1, 4]  gives  3  edits

[2, 3, 4, 1]  gives  3  edits

[2, 4, 1, 3]  gives  2  edits

[2, 4, 3, 1]  gives  2  edits

[3, 1, 2, 4]  gives  2  edits

[3, 1, 4, 2]  gives  2  edits

[3, 2, 1, 4]  gives  2  edits

[3, 2, 4, 1]  gives  2  edits

[3, 4, 1, 2]  gives  2  edits

[3, 4, 2, 1]  gives  2  edits

[4, 1, 2, 3]  gives  1  edits

[4, 1, 3, 2]  gives  1  edits

[4, 2, 1, 3]  gives  1  edits

[4, 2, 3, 1]  gives  1  edits

[4, 3, 1, 2]  gives  1  edits

[4, 3, 2, 1]  gives  1  edits

total is 50

Comment: if you want to see my code to calculate it, ask and I'll post--it's in python.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? Also, always post your code.

Comment: your question should be asked here http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: this is not a homework assignment--my friend got the question in an interview (but not the answer) so we're both trying to figure it out. I'll ask this again on the math page. a max_int would be an integer variable that stores the maximum value of the array so far, as the array is iterated through.

Answer (score 0):

For the case n=3 you have divided by 3 whereas you should have divided by 6, because there are 3! = 6 permutations of 3 objects.

You get the same probability of edits if you could generate random floating point numbers with so high a precision that there would be zero probability of ties - the probability of each permutation is the same.

With these numbers it is easy to see that the probability that the nth number will be the highest so far is 1/n. Therefore on average, the number of times you have to change the maximum so far is 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... 1/n. So e.g. for n=4 we have 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 = 25/12 and since there are 4!=24 permutations this matches your count of 50.

Looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number I don't see any neat closed form formula for this.